# Passing data between PHP sites in a scheduled task

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduled-tasks, moodle, data-transfer

This question has been answered in one form or another, none that I can see directly applying to this example.

I have a Moodle site and a Wordpress site on two separate servers. I need to regularly transfer data from the Moodle site to the Wordpress site inside a Moodle scheduled task. The is no cap on the volume of data that will be passed. I have already built the scaffolding for the scheduled task.

What I still need:

- A PHP script in Moodle that will send data securely to the WP site (both are https.) This script will be called regularly by the scheduled task. Not sure if this should use POST, curl or something else.
- A PHP script that I can place on the WP site. This does not need to have a user interface, just a web address that the PHP script in Moodle can send data to. When data is passed to the script, it will save it to the WP database.

If there is a better architecture than this please let me know. Otherwise, any advise on how to build these two scripts would be greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind the data needs to be transferred securely and I don't have time to build an API script. Also, I need to make sure other sites can't activate the receiving script on the WP site and inject data.

Comment: you can create rest api in moodle and hit it from wordpress with cron job

Comment: Unfortunately, the client requires the cron job to be in Moodle so they can edit it through the front end (turn it on, change the times it runs ect.)

Comment: Then let the cron job in moodle do the same i suggested through the moodle cronjob. when moodle cron job hit pass data to wordpress through api.

Comment: As I did mention in the Question I don't have time to build the API. I really need a quick dirty fix using Post or curl to pass the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done by making an API in Wordpress which will take a POST request, and by using a cron job on a script which will get the data stored in the database(assuming you are using a database), and then make a POST request in the WordPress API.

Cron Jobs tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Wordpress API tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introducing-the-wp-rest-api--cms-24533

--Edit--

Noticing that you said that you need a quick and dirty fix, you can probably use the same database and get the data through the database, that is the quickest solution i could think of.

Comment: Unfortunately they have to be on different database servers so that is not possible. Is there no way to securely and quickly send data using curl or POST?

Comment: Not exactly, if you want to use curl and POST you will need to make an API and then pass the data. I do not see any other option, hopefully, someone else could come up with a solution that may be right for you.

Comment: You were right in the end. There was no other option, I had to develop a Wordpress plugin and add the API script into it. Didn't take as long as I thought it would.

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help.